# STM32 - USB - CDC_Transmit - How to read the data on PC? - Matlab?

Tags: matlab, usb, stm32, oscilloscope, mcu

I am in the process of programming some sort of USB oscilloscope.

I followed the tutorial, using a STM32F429.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MmwR1VU_rVc&list=PLnMKNibPkDnHxpOv2HETihQy5HHQGv2nS&index=26

The tutorial was very helpful with this and I am able to use the software from the tutorial (stmscope) to see the incoming data.

However, I would like to process the data in Matlab, where my problems start. As far as I understand the baudrate does not matter, because there is no real UART connection?

For reading the UART in another project I used for example "Putty" or "SerialMonitor". By specifying the baudrate and the com port the readout was quite easy, even in Matlab.

The used USB port is simulated as a virtual com port and the data is sent with CDC_transmit. However, with the previous methods "Putty" or "SerialMonitor" I cannot read the sent data, because I have to specify a baudrate for this, which is unknown to me. Which program is suitable to monitor the incoming data?

In Matlab I also have the same problem that I have to specify a baudrate for the com port.

My goal is to evaluate the data in Matlab. Preferably I would like to read the data directly with Matlab from the virtual com port and save it in Matlab. If this is not possible I would first save the data to a txt.file and then read it into Matlab.

Are there any ready-made solutions or open source programs for this?

Thanks for reading and your help!

Comment: For virtual COM port, baudrate doesn't matter, correct (at least for standard ST CDC driver). Most probably the problem is in the code. When code is right, any serial-readers like putty would work with any br. There is also a small chance that windows virtual COM port driver hung (happened to me couple times); in this case, only full reboot can bring it back to life.

Comment: Putty definitely shows me something. However, what Putty displays is cryptic and probably nonsense. 
Image: https://imgur.com/a/df6g2b9

I'm a bit confused because of this, as the sample evaluation software shows correct data. Putty on the other hand does not. I would have expected Putty to display data in the value range 0 to 4095.

Comment: Ah, looks like it outputs data in binary format, not text. Evaluation software knows how to interpret that binary stream, while putty can only attempt to interpret it as stream of ASCII symbols, causing gibberish that you see.

Comment: I am able to see the data with Realterm in uint8_t format. However, I am not able to reconstruct the previous data. I am sending data in the range of 0 to 4095 (12 bit). The data is saved in a 16 bit format (half word) in a buffer with a size of 1000 numbers. Due to the size of 1000 the length should be 2000. I didn't understand the function of the buf at the beginnging of the CDC_Transmit command. Is it send in a uint8_t format? If so, how is it possible to convert the format into decimal format.

CDC_Transmit_FS((uint8_t*)buf,2000);

Comment: I tried it with sending the numbers 100, 200 and 300. 100 and 200 works fine but I suffered a stack overflow with 300 due to the uint8_t format. How can I handle this?